# SECURITY Flaws in this design for User authentication

Tags: python, authentication, pylons

SECURITY Flaws in this design for User authentication.

From:  http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonscookbook/Simple+Homegrown+Authentication

Note:
    a. Project follows the MVC pattern.
    b. Only a user with a valid username and password is allowed submit something.

Design:
    a. Have a base controller from which all controllers are derived from.
    b. Before any of the actions in the derived controllers are called the system calls a **before** action in the base controller.
    c. In each controller user hardcodes the actions that need to be verified in an array.
    d. The **before** action first looks in the array that has the actions that are protected and sees if a user is logged in or not by peaking into the session. If a user is present then user is allowed to submit otherwise user is redirected to login page.

What do you think?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Just trying to have some simple authentication in a website powered by pylons. I was wondering if the above approach will be safe or not.

Comment: in this case I'd use AuthKit
http://pylonsbook.com/en/1.1/authentication-and-authorization.html#authkit

Answer (score 1):

I prefer approach with decorating functions that require authentication because it does not require typing action name 2 times - in the function definition and in requires_auth list. In that case you can mistype action name and it would not be noticed by interpreter.
Decorating actions does not have this problem:

```
@authorize(ValidAuthKitUser())
def list(self):
    pass
```

You also can decorate __before__ function and it will have effect on all controller actions:

```
@authorize(ValidAuthKitUser())
def __before__(self):
    pass
def list(self): # automatically checks if the user is authenticated
    pass
```